# Are there any definitions of a fractional-grade multivector?

Tags: vectors

I am currently studying geometric algebra and I read that the unit vectors (grade 1 multivectors) (along with the wedge product) form a basis for all blades in the algebra. However, at least in the examples I have seen, this basis is discreet. That is, we normally have $$e_{k}, k = 1, 2, . . . n$$ where $n$ is the number of dimensions in our space. Have there been any attempts to define a similar algebra with $$e_{k}, 1 \leq k \leq n$$ where $k$ is now a continuous index? Might this allow one to construct fractional-grade multivectors? If not, are there any other ways one might construct fractional-grade multivectors, such as using fractional powers of the basis vectors?

Best,
MJR